# React : Is this possible to replace a "placeholder template tag" send as children?

Tags: reactjs, templating

I have for example this code below :

```
<AjaxForm>

    <input type="hidden" name="xxx" value="xxx" />

    <div className="grid">
        <div className="gdcol-xs-11">

            [[SUBMIT_BUTTON]]

        </div>
        <div className="gdcol-xs-11">

            [[CANCEL_BUTTON]]

        </div>
    </div>  

</AjaxForm>
```

And I would like, for example, be able in the AjaxForm component to replace the tag placeholder 'SUBMIT_BUTTON' by this :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>VALIDATE</a>
```

Is there a way to do this by iterating on this.props.children in the AjaxForm component ?

Is this possible to find some text pattern by crawling all the children ?

Should I have to use refs or a key ?

Thank you in advance !

---- EDIT

To add some informations, this is the render of the AjaxForm Component

```
return (
        <form action="" method="post" ref={this.ajaxRef} id={this.props.id} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value={this.props.id} />

            {this.props.children}

            <input type="submit" value="" className="fake-submit" />

            <div id={("ajax-") + this.props.id + ("-messages-container")} className="ajax-form-messages"></div>

        </form>
    )
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing it this way?

Comment: Yeap, ajaxForm is a component used for different forms and I want to be free to put some elements (like the submit button) wherever I want depending of the form

Comment: You say 'put the submit button wherever you want', but won't you get the opposite behaviour now? The submit button will always appear wherever you have written `[[SUBMIT_BUTTON]]`. Why not just put the actual submit button wherever you want?

Comment: And in general, you should be using `props` for this type of thing, not iterating over children.

Comment: @azium it's not the opposite behaviour because each time I will use the AjaxForm I will be able to specify where I want to put the submit button. If the button is embedded in the AjaxForm component I will not have a way to choose where to render it. I'm not sure to understand your second answer related to the props but I don't think it will help to resolve the main problem that is : "Is there a way to specify a placeholder tag in the children and replace it with whatever I want ?"

Comment: In your example code, `[[SUBMIT_BUTTON]]` is in a specific location though... how would you be able to put it wherever you want?

Comment: I agree with @azium; using `children` is not the proper approach here, but rather passing your "action" buttons in as `props` is preferred.

Comment: @azium AjaxForm is a component that can be reusable on multiple interfaces. So yes, for this form I specified to be at this location, but when I will set an other interface using this component (AjaxForm) I will specify an other location in the structure by using this "tag" system !

Comment: @lux the button have to be generated in the AjaxForm component for some internal reasons. Like I said previously the question here is about "How to replace a 'tag' / 'placeholder' send as children" ?

Comment: What are you wrapping `AjaxForm` with? Otherwise, where are the `children` coming from?

Comment: I hope my answer clears up your confusion here. Replacing placeholder tags is not the correct solution to your problem because `{ this.props.placeholder }` already exists.. this is what React was designed to do. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: @azium I'm not speaking about the placeholder attribute in html !

Comment: I use the word "tag / placeholder" to define an element that will be replaced by something else

Comment: An exemple of the principle of placeholder tags in templating : http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/introduction/templates_placeholders.html

Comment: no no.. i'm using placeholder just as a word not the attribute... it can be `[this.props.anythingYouWantToCallThis}`

Comment: @lux and I have been doing React for a long enough time that we know what we're talking about. I suggest you listen to our advice.. otherwise you're never going to get the answer you want.

Comment: React is *all about templating* and in React you use `this.props`. That's just how it works...

Comment: @azium my bad for the misunderstanding about 'placeholder'. I will check your answer below and give you feedback on it ! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your issue now. You're *generating* a component inside `AjaxForm` and you want to be able to place that component dynamically. In that case you should create another component called `AjaxFormContents` (or whatever your specific form should be called) which receives your generated component via props and places it wherever you want.

```
// AjaxForm.js

...
render() {
  return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { 
    submitButton: this.generateSubmitButton() // or however you're doing it
  })
}
...
```

Now whatever component you put as a child will have access to this component.

```
// AjaxFormContents.js

...
render() {
  return ( // arrange your form contents however you like!
    <div>
      <input />
      { this.props.submitButton }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then in your parent component:

```
// Parent.js

...
render() {
  return (
    <AjaxForm>
      <AjaxFormContents />
    </AjaxForm>
  )
}
```

This should work, however another approach -- using a higher order component (HOC) would be a nice solution here as well, because your `AjaxForm` doesn't display anything, it just wraps your form contents.. instead `AjaxForm` can be an HOC which passes a generated submit button component to the wrapped component.

```
var ajaxForm = function (WrappedComponent) {
  return React.createClass({
    generateSubmitButton() {
      return <a>your special submit button </a>
    },

    render() {
      <WrappedComponent submitButton={ this.generateSubmitButton() } />
    }
  })
}
```

Then you can have the exact same `AjaxFormContents` component as above and when you export it:

```
// or module.exports, whichever one you're using.
export default ajaxForm(AjaxFormContents)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I will try this tomorrow and give you a feedback !